# Im getting a null exception in a JpaQuery spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Im using JpaRepository, Hibernate and spring-boot with nativeQuery for my project and Im getting a really weird null value when executing my query, here is the code:

First goes my repository code(this is the one that returns null):

```
public interface PaquetesRepository extends JpaRepository<Paquetes, Integer>{

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM paquetes WHERE tipousuario_id = ?#{#tipoUser}", nativeQuery = true)
    Paquetes getPaqueteDelUsuario(int tipoUser);

}
```

Here a picture showing that it does have data:
[image]

Second my Service code:

```
@Override
    public Paquetes getPaqueteDelUsuario(int tipoUser) {
        System.out.println("Check: " + paquetesRepository.getPaqueteDelUsuario(tipoUser) + " , " + tipoUser);
        return paquetesRepository.getPaqueteDelUsuario(tipoUser);
    }
```

My debug returns = `Check: null , 2`

And in my controller I call it like this:

```
Paquetes paquete = paqueteService.getPaqueteDelUsuario(tipo);
System.out.println("Paquete: " + paquete);
```

The println returns = `Paquete: null`

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.21</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

<pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

And my Application.properties:

```
# ===============================
# = Conexion con la base de datos
# ===============================
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://url
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password =pass
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
# ===============================
# = Thymeleaf configuracion
# ===============================
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
# ===============================
# = Multipart Files
# ===============================
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

# ==============================================================
# = Spring Security / Queries para el Authentication 
# ==============================================================
spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, active from user where email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?
spring.queries.pais-query=SELECT * FROM pais
spring.queries.tipousuario-query=SELECT * FROM tipoUsuario
```

This is my StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "paquete.getTipo()" (usuario/Paquetes)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "paquete.getTipo()" (usuario/Paquetes)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:161)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariable(VariableExpression.java:154)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:59)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:103)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:133)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:120)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.getText(AbstractStandardTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.java:68)
    org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.getModifiedChildren(AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.java:59)
    org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractChildrenModifierAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractChildrenModifierAttrProcessor.java:59)
    org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
    org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E:(pos 8): Method call: Attempted to call method getTipo() on null context object
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwIfNotNullSafe(MethodReference.java:144)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueRef(MethodReference.java:73)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:66)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:267)
    org.thymeleaf.spring4.expression.SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SpelVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:139)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariable(VariableExpression.java:154)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:59)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:103)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:133)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:120)
    org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.getText(AbstractStandardTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.java:68)
    org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.getModifiedChildren(AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.java:59)
    org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractChildrenModifierAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractChildrenModifierAttrProcessor.java:59)
    org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
    org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
    org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the repository class:

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM paquetes WHERE tipousuario_id = ?1", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Paquetes getPaqueteDelUsuario(Integer tipoUser);
```

Alternate option, you can use a named query (without using nativeQuery)

```
paquetesRepository.getPaqueteDelUsuarioByTipousuarioId(tipoUser);
```

For this to work, you'll have to rename the variable in your Entity class because it contains an underscore.

```
@Column(name = "tipousuario_id", nullable = false)
private Integer tipousuarioId;
```

Reference link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: That did the trick thanks, any idea why its working this way but not how I had it?

Comment: You were using a spel expression in where clause, but as per the documentation looks like it is supported only for the entityName as of now (section 2.3.6 in the link I posted).